# DHTMLX combo issue

Tags: php, javascript

I'm tring to use DHTMLX combobox, I guess I included in my code all that I need, find code snippet below:

```
    <script>
        window.dhx_globalImgPath = "/resources/javascript/codebase/imgs/";
        </script>
        <link rel="STYLESHEET" type="text/css"
            href="/resources/javascript/codebase/dhtmlxcombo.css">
        <script src="/resources/javascript/codebase/dhtmlxcommon.js"></script>
        <script src="/resources/javascript/codebase/dhtmlxcombo.js"></script>
        <script>
function doOnLoad() {
    var z = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone", "alfa", 200);
    z.enableFilteringMode(true, "php/loadCombo.php", true, true);
}
</script>

        <div id="combo_zone" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;"></div>
```

Anyone can tell me if there is something wrong in my code?

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Code wrapped in onLoad which seems never triggered, just change code as

```
<div id="combo_zone" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;"></div>
<script>
    var z = new dhtmlXCombo("combo_zone", "alfa", 200);
    z.enableFilteringMode(true, "php/loadCombo.php", true, true);
</script>
```